# Return a function with receiver in Golang

Tags: go

I am new to Golang. And I am trying to use a decorator which returns a function with a receiver. How can I do that?

```
type myStruct struct {
    s string
}

func myFunc(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}

// Here I want to return a function with a receiver
func (*myStruct) myDecorator(fn func(string)) (*myStruct)func(string){
    return (ms *myStruct)func(s string) {
        fn(ms+s)
    }
}

func main() {
    ms := myStruct{"Hello"}
    // Some func is function with receiver as myStruct pointer
    someFunc := myDecorator(myFunc)
    // This is expected to print "Hello world"
    ms.someFunc(" world")
}
```

Comment: Higher-order function return values is possible, but you cannot return a function which has a receiver on another type. Please expand your question to describe more concretely what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Cosmic Ossifrage - If needed, the `myDecorator` function could have a receiver as `*myStruct`. I am actually using this decorator to wrap `fmt.Sprintf`, `Sprintln`, `Sprint` method to get `Logger.Debugln`, `Logger.Debugf`, `Logger.Warning`, ... methods, where `Logger` is a self-defined struct, since these functions shares almost the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194070/return-a-function-with-receiver-in-golang?noredirect=1#comment91337965_52194070), you cannot modify the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of a type in the return from a function call, so directly extending the behavior of the `myStruct` struct is not possible in your "decorator" function as written.

> I am actually using this decorator to wrap `fmt.Sprintf`, `Sprintln`, `Sprint` method to get `Logger.Debugln`, `Logger.Debugf`, `Logger.Warning`, ... methods, where `Logger` is a self-defined struct, since these functions shares almost the same behavior.

You also will not be able to pass around the `fmt.Sprintf`, `fmt.Sprintln` and `fmt.Sprint` functions in a generic way, as they share different signatures:

```
func Print(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

so you will need to wrap these methods separately.

It isn't entirely clear to me how you are seeking to wrap those methods to produce your `Logger` type.

If you require each of those methods at the top level of your logger, they will need to be explicitly declared in your logging package or on your `Logger` type's interface. You cannot dynamically bind each level function at runtime, despite their obvious similarities; go is a statically-typed language so your types must be declared upfront.

Defining the types explicitly will be the clearest solution, which is also in keeping with a key [go proverb](https://go-proverbs.github.io/): ["Clear is better than clever."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=14m35s)

If necessary, you can declare each method as a simple wrapper of an internal method on your type which actually performs the printing logic, keeping repetition to a minimum.

Here's a quick example I threw together to show the logic for some `Debug`, `Debugf` and `Debugln` endpoints. You can see the core logic is handled by a generic set of methods on the `Logger` type, and you can imagine how endpoints for other log levels could be trivially implemented.

If repetition is *really* a problem, you could trivially write a code generator to automatically generate the log-level specific methods, calling on the core functionality explicitly declared in the various print functions. Remember you can declare receivers for a type in multiple source files in the same package, allowing some methods to be generated in some source files while others are implemented explicitly elsewhere.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type Level string

const (
    Debug Level = "DEBUG"
    Error       = "ERROR"

// etc.
)

type Logger struct {
    writer       io.Writer
    prependLevel bool
}

func (l *Logger) print(level Level, msg string) {
    var s string
    if l.prependLevel {
        s = string(level) + ": "
    }
    s += msg
    fmt.Fprint(l.writer, s)
}

func (l *Logger) printf(level Level, format string, a ...interface{}) {
    l.print(level, fmt.Sprintf(format, a...))
}

func (l *Logger) println(level Level, msg string) {
    l.printf(level, "%s\n", msg)
}

func (l *Logger) Debug(msg string) {
    l.print(Debug, msg)
}

func (l *Logger) Debugf(format string, a ...interface{}) {
    l.printf(Debug, format, a...)
}

func (l *Logger) Debugln(msg string) {
    l.println(Debug, msg)
}

func main() {
    logger := Logger{os.Stderr, true}
    logger.Debugln("A plain message with a new line")
    logger.Debugf(
        ("The most customizable log entry with some parameters: " +
            "%s %v\n"),
        "myStr", false,
    )
    logger.Debug("A bare print statement")
}
```

[Playground link.](https://play.golang.org/p/Bf_yQdtF8b2)

---

## Third-party packages

In case you haven't yet done so, there are many third-party logging packages in Go which I would recommend considering, or at least assessing their interfaces to determine how others have approached similar tasks.

Logrus is a Go logger with levels, for example. You can see in their source files how they explicitly declare their interface for each function at each log level, while using a more comprehensive version of the method above to reduce repetition in the core logging implementation: [Interface](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/3791101e143bf0f32515ac23e831475684f61229/logrus.go#L112-L150) [Formatter implementations](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/3791101e143bf0f32515ac23e831475684f61229/entry.go#L199-L244)